# Why was this edit to repair dead links rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

As far as I can tell, [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17300000) simply fixes a dead link, yet it was rejected by two users as "not making post easier to read...".

Is fixing dead links not something we should be doing via edit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reviewers don't always get it right. This is pure speculation, but they probably thought the edit was too minor to be helpful. It wasn't.

Thanks for taking the time to find the correct links, went ahead and updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if some of them use the markdown view. In this case, there is seemingly no change. Is there no way to respond to a rejected edit?

Comment: @cloudworks I don't think there is a way to respond. If this happens again, you could simply post a comment to the answer and let the original author fix the links.